# Is the following a valid Bogoliubov transformation?

Tags: quantum-optics

Consider the Hamiltonian:

$$H_1=b^{\dagger}b+\lambda (b+b^{\dagger})+\frac{1}{2}+\lambda^2$$

The Bogoliubov transformation: $$a=b+\lambda$$ and $$a^{\dagger}=b^{\dagger}+\lambda^*$$

makes the above hamiltonian:$$H_2=a^{\dagger}a+\frac{1}{2}$$

Now let $\lambda$ be an operator $\hat\lambda$ such that,

$[\hat\lambda,\hat\lambda^{\dagger}]=1$ $\ \ $and $\ \ $ $[\hat\lambda,b]=0$.

Would the transformation: $$a=\frac{b+\hat\lambda}{\sqrt2}$$ and $$a^{\dagger}=\frac{b^{\dagger}+\hat\lambda^{\dagger}}{\sqrt2}$$

be a valid Bogoliubov Transformation?

Comment: This is a valid unitary/canonical transformation. Bogoliubov transformations are usually udnerstood in a narrower sense, as the ccanonical tarnsformations mixing creation and annihilation operators https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogoliubov_transformation

Answer (score 1):

A transformation is valid if it preserves the canonical commutation relations.

In your case, you need
$ [a,a^\dagger] = 1$.
Evaluating your proposed transformation, we get
$$[a, a^\dagger] = \frac{1}{2} [b+\lambda,b^\dagger + \lambda^\dagger]$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\left([b,b^\dagger] + [\lambda, \lambda^\dagger] \right) = 1$$

So, at least in terms of preserving commutators, the $a$'s are indeed bosons. However, the Hamiltonian you have described cannot be expressed in terms only of $a$'s - it's non-Hermitian, and you'd need to introduce another operator along the lines of $\chi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(b - \lambda)$ to remove all occurrences of $b$ and $\lambda$. In fact, even with the $\lambda$ interpreted as scalars, the transformation you've described is only correct if $\lambda$ is real:

$$a^\dagger a + \frac{1}{2} = (b^\dagger + \lambda^*)(b+\lambda) + \frac{1}{2} $$

To fix your (operator-$\lambda$) Hamiltonian, you would instead need to do

$$H = b^\dagger b + \lambda^\dagger b + \lambda b^\dagger + \lambda^\dagger \lambda + \frac{1}{2}$$

which is Hermitian and Bogoliubov-transformable to a SHO, and reduces to the original Hamiltonian if you demote $\lambda$ to a real scalar.